# Как запустить скрипт после окончания рендеринга списка Vue?

Tags: javascript, циклы, vue.js, swiper

У меня есть карусель (http://idangero.us/swiper/) и я хочу использовать ее в блоке с v-for. Но у меня не получается инициализировать swiper в этом цикле, так как список еще не дорендерился получается каша.

Я пробовал так:

```
<div class="swiper-slide" v-for="(item, index) in items">
    <div v-if="index == items.length-1 ? initSwiper() : ''">
        <!-- slides -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Но все равно не получается. Как сделать правильно?

Comment: [Vue.js does an event trigger after component has been rendered?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34997958/2881286)

Comment: вам нужно написать кастомный компонент и использовать хук mounted или updated

Answer (score 0):

Я добавил setTimeout 0 в методе initSwipe так:

```
initSwiper() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // init swiper
    }, 0);
}
```

Работает, но не работают кнопки nextButton и prevButton :( Как исправить?